# Conversion to Unix timestamp is not working

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert `DateTime` to Unix timestamp.

```
static long ToUnixTime(DateTime dateTime)
  {
      var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);
       return dateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
  }
```

But this function always return timestamp equal to something "Sun Jan 18 1970" instead of current DateTime. What is wrong with this?

Comment: What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: Works fine here.  It returns seconds since the epoch on Jan 1, 1970, exactly as expected.

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.6.1, that supports this method.

Comment: @Amy, I need to get timestamp equal to current DateTime.

Comment: Well what are you passing in?  I tested with `DateTime.Now` and got the expected value.

Comment: The current date as expressed as a Unix timestamp is 1501093539, more or less.  What are you expecting?  What are you getting?  What are you passing into your method?  I think you're checking yourself wrong; if I edit my code to add **milliseconds**, I get `1/18/1970`.  But unix times aren't in milliseconds.  They're in **seconds**

Comment: @Amy, that's the point!!!! You may add this as answer.

Comment: Okay, I will do so.

Comment: @Amy, probably you got me wrong. I mean that you're right. I forgot about difference in seconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current date as expressed as a Unix timestamp is 1501093539, more or less.

I think you're checking yourself wrong; if I edit my code to add milliseconds, I get `1/18/1970`. But unix times aren't in **milliseconds**. They're in **seconds**.

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var offset = new DateTimeOffset(dt);
var unix = offset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

dt = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
dt = dt.AddSeconds(unix);
Debug.WriteLine(dt);        // gives current date back
```

Change it to `AddSeconds` and you'll get the current date.  Change it to `AddMilliseconds` and you'll get January 18th, 1970.  Your code is actually fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will give you Unix time stamp with any version of the framework

```
public static class UnixDateTime
{
    private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static long GetUnixTimestamp(this DateTime input)
    {
        return (long)(input - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

Then just use the extension method

```
var unixTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.GetUnixTimestamp();
```